# Cannot start visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I cannot start Visual Studio Professional 2017 after update, it only appears less then 1 second and disappear. I'll try to repair, uninstall and install fresh new one, but I get same problem. Maybe someone had same problem ? What kind solutions you made ?

Answer (score 0):

Please first check the system requirement here:

> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs

If your system requirement is satisfied, then remove all the old cache file like disk cleanup, %temp% files. Restart the system and try to install and run.
thanks